# Delphi - can a property read from a property?

Tags: delphi, properties

So I just joined this forum because I could not find an answer to my simple question.

I want to declare a read-only property, and it should read from a private members read-only property. It seems like that won't work. Can I work myself around that blockade?

Here is the code snippet:

```
    property Mine: TMineType read mMine.MineType;
```

Edit: Maybe I should clarify. mMine is of class TMine, which has a property MineType. MineType is of type TMineType and is read-only.

Comment: When you say private members property do you refer to the property that is declared in the same class or the property that is declared in parent class?

Comment: @SilverWarrior I was refering to a property that is declared in the same class. But right now I already learned that what I tried to do wasn't possible without a handwritten getter.

Comment: If that property is declared in the same class why don't you simply change if visibility from private to public. Also bare in mind that you can have multiple properties accessing the same field. So you can have a private property that is able to both read and write to that field and then a public property that is only able to read from that field.

Comment: @SilverWarrior Super sorry, I was wrong. That property is declared in another class. Still, as a newbie, I believe there was some pretty valuable information in your comment, so thank you. I'll probably need that pretty often.

Comment: I have provided an answer with some more information about working with class properties that might come useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your additional information that you provided in your comments (such information should be put into the original question itself right from the start) I believe I can provide an answer which would hopefully provide solution to the problem you are facing.

In the code bellow I'm showing of how you can make parent class property accessible through descendant class by using property forwarding or property publishing.

```
  //Base class we use
  TBaseClass = class(TObject)
  //Private section. Methods, fields and properties declared here are only visible from within classes declared in same unit
  //but not from classes or method declared in other units.
  private
    FPrivateField: Integer;
    function GetPrivateField: Integer;
    procedure SetPrivateField(AValue: Integer);
    //This property is making use of getter and setter methods in order to access FPrivateField
    property PrivateFieldProperty: Integer read GetPrivateField write SetPrivateField;
  //Strict private section. Methods, fields and properties declared here are only visible from descendant classes and their
  //methods but not from other classes and their methods even if they are declared in the same unit.
  strict private
    FStrictPrivateField: Integer;
    function GetStrictPrivateField: Integer;
    procedure SetStrictPrivateField(AValue: Integer);
  //Public section. Methods, Field and properties declared here are visible from any other class or methods regardless of
  //where they are declared
  public
    //This property is accessing its field directly
    property DirectPrivateFieldProperty: Integer read FPrivateField write FPrivateField;
    //This property is making use of getter and setter methods in order to access FStrictPrivateField
    property StrictPrivateFieldProperty: Integer read GetStrictPrivateField write SetStrictPrivateField;
  end;

  //Sub class is actually a descendant class from our base class
  TSubClass = class(TBaseClass)
  public
    //If your parent class already has declared certain property and you want to use that property in your descendant
    //class you can use so called "property forwarding" approach where you only specify the parents property name that
    //you want to make available to your descendant class. This approach only allows accessing fields that are declared
    //in parents class.
    //If you need to access field declared in descendant class then its property must directly access that field or use
    //getter and/or setter methods declared in descendant class. Such approach is called property overloading.
    property DirectPrivateFieldProperty;
    property PrivateFieldProperty;
    //If you want to limit the access level of a descendants class property (making it read only) you need to follow standard
    //property declaration guideline where you declare property type and the field to which it is accessing either directly or
    //by using getter or setter methods
    property ReadOnlyPrivateFieldProperty1: Integer read FPrivateField;
    property ReadOnlyPrivatefieldProperty2: Integer read GetPrivateField;
    //You can also declare forwarded descendant class property with different visibility of the one declared in parent class.
    //Such approach is usually referred as property publishing.
    property StrictPrivateFieldProperty;
  end;
```

Note the above approaches only work when accessing properties or fields of a parent class from a descendant class but not for accessing fields or properties of other classes.

The reason for this is that property may only directly access fields of its own class or any parent classes.

Also property can only use getter and setter methods that are declared either in its own class or in any of the parent classes.

I hope this answer of mine might give you better idea about working with properties.

Now at the moment I guess properties might look a bit confusing to you but believe me when you will learn to work with them you will realize of how powerful they can actually be. I must admit that I'm still finding out new ways to use them in my projects every now and then.

Comment: I thought I had all the information needed in my original question, I guess that wasn't the case. I'm sorry, I'm new here.

Your answer is beyond useful. Like you guessed, I'm still at the beginning of my learning progress with delphi, and I'm glad I decided to work with properties. Now that I believe I know much more about how they work, I'm going to give that property forwarding a try. 
Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2):

A property getter can be one of two things:

- A field, or
- A function.

Your code attempts to implement the getter with a property, and that does not meet the requirement stated above.

The documentation contains all the details: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties

Comment: How great would it be if the compiler would be smart enough to just auto generate code for such a getter.

Comment: Probably not very great, @Stefan. How often have you actually needed something like this? Rarely, I suspect.

Comment: If you practice encapsulation you often come into situations where you instead of making an entire object public only make specific properties public. So yes I have written quite some one line getters and setters in my life that just delegate.

Answer (score 2):

On a practical level, you could do something like this:

```
function GetMineType : TMineType;
begin
  result := mMine.MineType;
end;

property Mine: TMineType read GetMineType;
```

If you declare the GetMineType function as inline it will not generate any code.

Comment: As simple as your answer might seem, I couldn't think of it. That was really helpful.